# How to check if a function is defined? Python noob

Tags: python

I'm quite new to programing and after spending 3 hours trying to figure out why this was not working i couldn't.

```
import wget

print("Serverstall By Logix1") #Prints Info At start

print("Here comes the real code!")

class ServerSelector:
    def _init__(self, ServerType, PowerRequired):
        self.ServerType = USRchoice1
        self.PowerRequired = USRchoice2
    USRchoice1 = input("What server type to do want to create?")
    USRchoice2 = input("Please choose the amount of ram required?")
    def GarrysMod(self):
        if USRchoice1 is ("GarrysMod"):
            print("Nice! Great Choice!")
```

It doesn't print `Nice Great Choice` after entering `GarrysMod`? Anyone know whats wrong?

Comment: I wanted to suggest [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is) as a possible duplicate, but turns out, you never call the function, so it's never executed

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! If applicable, please [edit] your question to include the portion of code where you instantiate a `ServerSelector` object and call the `GarrysMod` method on it. If you don't have code that does that, then that's the issue

Comment: Also note that it's kinda weird -- and probably not what you want to be doing -- to have statements inside a class that aren't attribute or method definitions.

Comment: @G.Anderson means that you never do something like `my_server_selector = ServerSelector(bla, bla)`. @Lagerbaer means that the `USRchoice1/2 = ...` lines are executed as the class is loaded, but the way this code is structured. nothing is done with the values.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
Your post includes unrelated code, and you failed to include the code that uses the Class in any way: no instantiation, and you never call the function in question.  This is not (yet) an issue of whether the function gets defined.

Comment: There's a lot that's wrong here. Step back and go over some tutorials about classes, or maybe avoid them entirely until you're more familiar with Python in general.

Comment: @Prune: No, this probably is their actual full code that does reproduce the problem.

Comment: You _defined_ a function named `GarrysMod`, but you never _called_ it.

Comment: @Junuxx I'm afraid that might be the case; however, OP claims that execution *did* enter `GarrysMod`, which would require code that isn't posted here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the things `USRchoice1` and 2 are not part of self, and you do not call the function. You are not instanciating an object anyways. So nothing happens.

```
import wget

print("Serverstall By Logix1") #Prints Info At start

print("Here comes the real code!")

class ServerSelector:
    def __init__(self, ServerType, PowerRequired):
        self.ServerType = ServerType
        self.PowerRequired = PowerRequired
        if self.ServerType is ("GarrysMod"):
            print("Nice! Great Choice!")

USRchoice1_tmp = input("What server type to do want to create?")
USRchoice2_tmp = input("Please choose the amount of ram required?")
My_selector = ServerSelector(USRchoice1_tmp, USRchoice2_tmp )
```

Therefore, not the existence of your function seems to be the problem, but your general structure of the code.
Edit/Addition: the init has to be spelled `__init__` with two _ on both sides. Notice your code above has only one _ in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Python provides various methods to check if variables/methods are defined.

For Global Variables/Functions

```py
def C():
   pass

MY_FUNC_NAME = "C"
NOT_MY_FUNC_NAME = "c"

print(MY_FUNC_NAME in locals()) # True
print(NOT_MY_FUNC_NAME in locals()) # False
```

For Class Methods/Variables

```
class MyClass:
   def C():
      pass


MY_METH_NAME = "C"
NOT_MY_METH_NAME = "c"

print(MY_METH_NAME in dir(MyClass)) # True
print(NOT_MY_METH_NAME in dir(MyClass)) # False
```

Comment: This might answer the question in the title, but does not solve OP's issue at all.